# Why doesnt "export" works in linux system() cmd to set a linux shell environment variable at runtime?

Tags: linux, shell

I was trying to set a linux shell environment variable at run time in software using system() command. In the target, couldn't see it set.
for eg.

```
snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "export A=%s", "luck");
system(buf);
```

Tried `/bin/sh -c "export A=B"` in the target run time and had no success.

Comment: You can't modify the environment of a parent process. The best you can do is to `source` a shell script.  The environment modules package works around this problem using aliases that source a shell script produced by a program.

Comment: `man setenv` `man putenv`

Comment: I tried setenv and putenv before posting this query. My bad not to mention it. Thanks anyways. For some reason, the setenv and putenv doesn't work in my linux shell. I did try sourcing a script which does the export/unset of environment variables. It worked well. Unfortunately i didnt have enough reputations to vote for the answers. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The `system` call starts a new shell and runs the command in there.
The environment variable will be set in that shell only.

To set an environment variable in your own process, use [putenv](http://linux.die.net/man/3/putenv).